# Use Check Constraints to determine if a bit column and be set to true based on another column value, possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

To elabortate,

is it possible to enforce a rule where ONLY one record entry can have a column named 'IsPrimaryUser' set to true, whereas all others grouped by another column are set to false. The condition for deciding which entry will have a true 'IsPrimaryUser' field will be the CompanyId column.

I am only interested in whether it can be done using check constraints. Obviously, there is a SQL approach to something like this.

Example:

User Table

int UserId   |  int CompanyId   |   bit IsPrimaryUser

Data:

```
UserId  |  CompanyId  | IsPrimaryUser
   1          1              1
   2          1              0
   3          1              0
   4          1              0
   5          2              1
   6          2              0
   7          2              0
   8          2              0
```

Comment: This seems like a non-optimal arrangement.  Why not have a PrimaryUser table with columns CompanyID and PrimaryUser with CompanyID as the primary key?

Comment: Why are you only interested in whether it can be done using check constraints? A unique filtered index would do the job easily.

Comment: @Martin simply because I know relatively little about them and curious as to how flexible they can be

Comment: I agree with Martin: a unique filtered index is the proper way to handle this.

Comment: @Matthew - Well I think they can be used but there are a lot of things to be careful of RE: [snapshot isolation](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2006/07/21/Snapshot-and-integrity-part-1.aspx) and [multi row updates](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/06/25/scalar-udfs-wrapped-in-check-constraints-are-very-slow-and-may-fail-for-multirow-updates.aspx).

Comment: @Jack I sat down and thought about it. Using a table that just houses the keys of UserId that represent Primary Users is a much better solution and completely feasible. Unfortunately, it doesn't really answer the question =(   But nonetheless thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Constraints only work on a single row, but you can use scalar UDFs within the constraint.

You can breach the single-row check by using UDFs that check other rows in the table. Although unlike a trigger where you can access the DELETED virtual table and process individually, SQL Server seems to hold the records in a sort of transaction, and perform a CHECK on EACH row after the change, then finally accepting or aborting the CRUD in batch.

See this test case

Create table

```
create table usertable (UserId int,
CompanyId int, IsPrimaryUser int)
```

Populate

```
insert usertable select
1, 1, 1 union all select
2, 1, 0 union all select
3, 1, 0 union all select
4, 1, 0 union all select
5, 2, 1 union all select
6, 2, 0 union all select
7, 2, 0 union all select
8, 2, 0
```

Scalar function helper

```
create function dbo.anyprimaryuser(@userid int, @company int) returns bit as
begin
return
    case when exists (
    select * from usertable
    where companyid=@company and isprimaryuser=1 and userid<>@userid)
    then 1 else 0 end
end
```

The CHECK constraint

```
alter table usertable add constraint usertable_ck1
check (isprimaryuser=0 or dbo.anyprimaryuser(userid,companyid)=0)
```

Tests

```
insert usertable select 9,2,1 -- fail

insert usertable select 9,2,0 -- ok

insert usertable select 19,4,1 union all select 20,4,0 -- ok

insert usertable select 19,3,1 union all select 20,3,0 union all select 21,3,1
-- not ok, accepting the multi-row insert will breach the constraint

update usertable set IsPrimaryUser=1-IsPrimaryUser where CompanyId=4
-- ok! sets one and unsets the other in one go
```

*(note) I updated the answer after Martin's comment below*

Comment: You can call a scalar UDF from a check constraint but it's all a bit of an unnecessary hassle.